# Connect to server via ssh, check if chef is installed and record servers that it is not installed on

Tags: python, ssh, chef-infra, pxssh

I need to check a lot of servers if they have chef installed (Don't ask) I was trying to automate it instead of doing it manually. I have never used python before and I can't really test this until I go in tomorrow so was looking for some feed back if I am on the right track.I figure I dump all the IP address's into a text file, loop through it and save the ones that need to have chef installed.

```
import pxssh
import getpass
CheckIT = str("command not found")

for line in open('ServerList.txt','r').readlines():

try:                                                            
s = pxssh.pxssh()
hostname = raw_input('line ')
username = raw_input('username ')
password = getpass.getpass('password: ')
s.login (hostname, username, password)
s.sendline ('sudo su -')   # run a command
s.prompt()             # match the prompt
s.sendline ('chef-client')
s.prompt()
if CheckIT == readline(self,size=-1)
with open("ServersToUpdate.txt", "a") as myfile:
myfile.write(hostname)


except pxssh.ExceptionPxssh, e:
print "pxssh failed on login."
print str(e)
```

Comment: The single check "if Chef is installed" on its own does not really make sense without further steps. What would you like to do with the nodes that have or have not Chef installed further?

Comment: If it is not installed then I need to install it, if it is installed no further action.

Comment: Why not bootstraping each and every node then straight away?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so you probably won't want to actually run Chef as part of this. Also never ever use `sudo su -`, to correct way to write that for the past 15 years has been `sudo -i`, but you don't need even that. Just run `chef-client --version` and if that fails, assume Chef isn't installed.